# How can I open a file with it's default program via a package.json script

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, package.json

How I do I make it so running `npm start` opens image.png in windows photo viewer?

```
{
    "name": "open-image",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "image.png"
    },
}
```

Comment: Consider utilising [open-cli](https://github.com/sindresorhus/open-cli).

Answer (score 1):

Open it with Explorer, and Explorer will choose the default program.

```
"start": "explorer.exe image.png"
```

Comment: additional note, the command might vary depending on the os

Comment: this seems to just open a generic explorer window for me (windows 11)

Comment: Ah... too bad, it works on Windows 10